# ZF One project with two different application_env

Tags: zend-framework

I'm developping a project with ZF. One part of the project is still in developing and the other is already in production. Controller A is in dev, Controller B is in prod. I have set my application_env in the htaccess file. How can I solve this problem? Regards Andrea

Comment: leave the production copy alone and put a copy of everything on a development box.

Comment: Unfortunately I have only one server for dev and prod...

Comment: If you absolutely have to develop on a remote server (as opposed to a localhost environment), see if you can't create a second host (vhost) to separate your live (production) environment from your development environment. You have to find some way to separate concerns, the server is either production or development it can't reasonably be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you use apache as a web server. Note that I can't do any tests to confirm this works exactly like typed but I hope you get the drift and that the E flag is your friend here.

```
RewriteRule ^/your-dev-path/.*$ index.php [NC,E=APPLICATION_ENV:development,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,E=APPLICATION_ENV:production,L]
```

The E flag allows linking an env to a specific rule and the L flag essentially makes it the last rule. Hence the last line (your default rule) should not apply once the previous one is a match.

Here's the link for the docu http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e

Comment: Hi, I tried this option but it seems not working. I checked it against this checker http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ and it seems ok, but not in my application. What do you mean exactly by: that the E flag is your friend ... ? Regards Andrea

Comment: .htaccess is read: I put some garbage in the .htaccess file and got internal server error. But the variable is not set: when testing it in the index.php... strange...

Comment: @cwhisperer  E flag is your friend for setting an environment variable only when a RewriteRule applies. If you use this method make sure you don't set the env with `SetEnv` as you usually do. Other than that it should work. I don't use this exact scenario but set another env this way and it works.